# org-babel new language

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'd like to run some code through a binary via stdin and paste the output. The language is [foma](http://code.google.com/p/foma/), is there a fast way for that or do I have to write my own definition? I've tried http://sprunge.us/DjOV, but that gives me a `if: Wrong type argument: stringp, (:colname-names)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If foma could be run an a file (rather than STDIN), then simply evaluating the following function definition should work.  This will write `body` to a temporary file, call `foma` on that file and return the output (collected from STDOUT).

```
(defun org-babel-execute:foma (body params)
  "Execute a block of Foma code with org-babel."
  (message "executing Foma source code block")
  (org-babel-eval "foma" body))
```

If `foma` insists on taking input through STDIN, then you could replace `foma` above with something like `foma-helper` where `foma-helper` is a shell script holding something like

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $1|foma
```

Hope this helps

Comment: There's an -f which evaluates a file, so this should work (with `foma -f` I assume)